# Is there a better workflow than editing HTML/CSS in SublimeText2 and then F5/refresh in browser to view changes?

Tags: css, html, browser, sublimetext2

At the moment, I have to alt-tab to browser after making changes in code, and press F5 to view changes in browser. Is there a way to refresh the browser automatically as changes are made ?

Comment: Live editing isn't that common, but it's starting to gain traction. Take a look at the Adobe Brackets editor: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/

Comment: You can put code in your page to auto-refresh the page after a certain amount of time and then remove it later when you're not developing.

Comment: http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/ or https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager#Prominent_tiling_window_managers

Comment: If you're on a MAC you can check out "[CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/)" as it has a feature called "**Live Browser Reloads**" which should be helpful.

Comment: There is, in the form of a Chrome Browser extension: [LiveReload-sublimetext2](https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2). Watch this [video](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/livereload/) from Tutsplus [Perfect Workflow in Sublime Text 2](https://tutsplus.com/course/improve-workflow-in-sublime-text-2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug allows you to edit CSS live, though it is a bit buggy. Still, it can be useful for minor edits. It may even have more capabilities than that which I haven't discovered.